# data search from db using date

Tags: java, hibernate, date

I am giving inout as dateofbirth and want to get the result.But query is printing in console without error but result is not result size is zero. Can any one please help me where i am doing mistake.Thanks in advanced.

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Date d1=sd.parse(VO.getMemberDOB());
    //code here
    memberNameQuery.setDate("dateOfBirth", d1);
searchResultsVOList = (List<Object[]>) memberNameQuery
                                .list();
```

in hbm

```
<property name="dateOfBirth" column="B_DOB_DT" type="java.util.Date"/>
```

in db 
 dateofbirth type is Date and format is (12-JAN-90)

Comment: did you try SimpleDateFormater("dd-MM-YY");

Comment: In my input it will take as "12/11/2015".

Comment: and how your database handles, date format

Comment: format is (12-JAN-90)

Comment: so your format must match that to be saved or searching